# LCD Output on RS232-connected Module via Ethernet - Request for general information

Tags: serial-port, lcd, dot-matrix

currently I am trying to write to an 20x4 LCD Dot-Matrix Module using [Perle's TruePort Redirector](http://www.perle.com/supportfiles/Trueport.shtml). I have the [GMS-DS](http://www.gms-ds.de/) LCD Module connected to a [Perle Serial to Ethernet Device Server](http://www.perle.com/products/IOLAN-DS-Terminal-Server.shtml). As of now, I think that I need to write to a local TruePort interface, which then converts the data and sends it to the Device Server via TCP/IP. Then the server forwards the data over the serial port to the LCD Module, which displays the characters.

I am at a very early stage and not able to describe a specific problem. I would rather ask around if anyone knowledgable about this particular setup or general LCD display output has a useful link to a tutorial, library or similar sources that could help getting me started.

Not sure about, whether this question should be asked on serverfault.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed this kind of setup.  I don't have any links but I'll give you some tips.

You have two separate tasks here. If possible (depending on what hardware you have available), solve them separately then combine the solutions.

1. Set up the device server with a loopback connector on its serial port.  If necessary, run  a networking utility to make sure it appears at the IP address you set it to, or to determine what DHCP address it got.  Install the Redirector and point it to that IP address.  Check that its virtual com port shows up in Device Manager.  Open a terminal program to the virtual comport. Type something, and see if you receive it back.
2. Get your program to control the device.  This will be easier if you get it working locally first. by connecting the serial device directly to a computer's serial port, (possibly via a USB-to-serial-port converter if your computer doesn't have a serial port).

Do you have any specific questions?